# Posting on a Page Wall via API as Page is not shown in the fans newsfeed

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

Posting on a Page Wall via API / APP is not shown in the fans newsfeed
Hi everybody,

i have a short question.

I build a tool that posts wall posts on a Facebook Fan Page. 
This is done not as me (admin) but as The Page itself.

This works fine so far.

The posts are shown on the Fan Page Wall 
The posts are submittet by the Fan page (with the correct Access token that allows the script to post as my in behalf off the page)

BUT:
The posts are not shown in the timeline of the fans that like the Fan Page. 
They are shown in my (admin) newsfeed. But definitiv not in the newsfeed of the fans.

Is there a difference if i post a post directly or commit it vie API ?

It would be quite useless to post on the wall if the fans do not get this post inside the newsfeed

Can anybody give me some research input on this ?

you can see it here

https://www.facebook.com/liebe.gefaelltmir.cc

the last three wall posts are made by the app vie api feed post,
they are on the wall but not in the newsfeed of the fans. (we checked)

when we look at the insight impressions hand made posts are twice as high as the impressions of api made posts. (11.000 vs. 5000) but even this - why do 5000 user not get this ?

Best regards
Sebastian

Answer (score 0):

This may be a result of a bug: https://developers.intern.facebook.com/bugs/151722701585098